# Iterate over array in wso2 esb

Tags: esb, wso2-esb

This is my context:
I have this body JSON:

```
 {
    "delivery": [
        {
            "note": "aaaaaa",
            "method": "x"
        },
        {
            "note": "bbb",
            "method": "y"
        },
        {
            "note": "ccc",
            "method": "x"
        }
    ],
    "partner": {
            "zip": "a",
            "country": "b",
            "city": "c"         
    }
}
```

I need to iterate over delivery array and create object (delivery item + partner object) and then make a call to an endpoint.

For example this the first object:

```
{
    "delivery": 
    {
        "note": "aaaaaa",
        "method": "x"
    }
    "partner": {
            "zip": "a",
            "country": "b",
            "city": "c"
    }
}
```

and then make call to endpoint

This operation will be repeat x = array.lenght

I create this sequence but it doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="tec_notif-expe_v1" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <in>    
        <property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" value="true"/>
        <property action="remove" name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2"/>
        <header action="remove" name="To"/>
        <property name="partner" expression="json-eval($.partner)" scope="default" /> 
        <!-- iterate over delivery-->
        <iterate continueParent="true" expression="//delivery">
            <target sequence="anon">
               <sequence>
                    <property name="deliveryItem" expression="//delivery" />

                    <script language="js"><![CDATA[
                        var body = {};
                        body.delivery = {};
                        body.partner = {};
                        body.delivery = mc.getProperty('deliveryItem');
                        body.partner = mc.getProperty('partner');

                        mc.setPayloadJSON(body);
                    ]]></script>
                     <call>
                        <endpoint key="update-eklem"/>
                    </call>
               </sequence>
            </target>
        </iterate>
        <send />
        <drop />    
    </in>
</sequence>
```

Would you have any propositions ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any error in the log? Try to add a log statement before and right after the iterate to see you're received content and if the xpath is right.

I've done the same with nested json arrays without any problems, except the xpath :-)

My received request looks like this.

```
{ 
    "jsonElement" : [{
        "val1" : "some Value",
        "val2" : "some Value"
        "array" : [{
            .... data
            "arrayVal1" : "array Val1",
            ....
        }]
    }]
}
```

In the sequence I added the following.

```
<iterate continueParent="true" expression="//jsonElement">
    .. get some values e.g. <property name="val1" expression="//val1/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <iterate expression="//array">
        <property name="arrayVal1" expression="//arrayVal1/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        .....
    </iterate>
</iterate>
```